# Why this code do not procedure the way I want?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code, the program dos not proceed in the way I want.
When I answer the second question, the program makes the same procedure as if I was answering the first question in the wrong way.
Can someone see where is my mistake?

```
my_money = 100
first_question = input("Who do you bet for? ")

if first_question == "tim" or first_question == "tess" or first_question == "alex" or first_question == "duck" or first_question  == "dog":

    bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))

    if bet < 0:
        print("The bet can't take negative valours! ")
        bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))
        while bet < 0:
            print("The bet can't take negative valours! ")
            bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))

    if bet > my_money:
        print("The bet can't be above the money you have! ")
        bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))
        while bet > my_money:
            print("The bet can't be above the money you have! ")
            bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))

    if bet >= 0 and bet <= my_money:
            total_money = my_money - bet

if first_question != "tim" or first_question != "tess" or first_question != "alex" or first_question != "duck" or first_question != "dog":
    print("There is no runner with that name. ")
    first_question = input("Who do you bet for?")
    while first_question != "tim" or "tess" or "alex" or "duck" or "dog":
        print("There is no runner with that name. ")
        first_question = input("Who do you bet for? ")
```

Comment: For clarity, can you post your input and the program's output when you run it?

Comment: Near the end, you have a line read `while first_question != "tim" or "tess" or "alex" or "duck" or "dog":`. This is not doing what you think it is. Instead of checking if `first_question` is not any of those values, it is only checking if `first_question != 'tim'`, and then checking the casted Boolean values of each string. Non-empty strings will return `True` (Try `bool("duck")` yourself!). So in the end, your while statement *actually* reads: `while (first_question != "tim") or True or True or True or True:` which of course evaluates to `while True` no matter what `first_question` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better version of the code and I think ill work fine for you.

```
myMoney = 100
runnerName = input("Who do you bet for? ")
runners = ["tim", "tess", "alex", "duck", "dog"]
while runnerName not in runners:
    print("There is no runner with that name. ")
    runnerName = input("Who do you bet for? ")


bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))

while bet < 0 and bet > myMoney:
    if bet < 0:
        print("The bet can't take negative valours! ")
        bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))
    else:
        print("The bet can't be above the money you have! ")
        bet = int(input("How much you bet? "))


moneyLeft = myMoney - bet #The program will reach here if the value of bet is between 0 and myMoney no need of if.
print(moneyLeft)
```

Comment: Thanks. But what was the problem with my first code?

Comment: @LittleBlue The while loop, in the end, is doing nothing after taking the input. It just takes the input and the program exits. Try making your code less redundant. This will help you better find bugs. I think you are a starter you'll learn slowly. The community is here to help anytime. :)

Comment: Yes, I am a starter xD

Comment: One more thing, How can I set a max distance that the turtle can go?